# Angular 6 Material: mat-tab-link be selected by underlining bar

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, navigationbar

I have a `mat-tab-nav-bar` navigation bar for my website, but the `mat-tab-link` blue underlining bar won't chase the active button. It just stays at the first button, and doesn't move. The buttons do turn into active state though in the sense that the background color changes, and they route well to their corresponding pages.

Here's the `app.component.ts`:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {
  navLinks = [
    { path: '', label: 'The Problem' },
    { path: 'the-solution', label: 'The Solution' },
    { path: 'the-game', label: 'The Game' },
    { path: 'probability-calculator', label: 'Probability calculator' },
  ];
}
```

And here's the `app.component.html`:

```
<nav mat-tab-nav-bar>
  <a mat-tab-link
     *ngFor="let link of navLinks"
     [routerLink]="link.path"
     routerLinkActive #rla="routerLinkActive"
     [active]="rla.isActive">
    {{link.label}}
  </a>
</nav>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Here is the `app.module.ts`:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { MatTabsModule } from '@angular/material/tabs';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { TheProblemComponent } from './the-problem/the-problem.component';
import { TheSolutionComponent } from './the-solution/the-solution.component';
import { ProbabilityCalculatorComponent } from './probability-calculator/probability-calculator.component';
import { TheGameComponent } from './the-game/the-game.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    TheProblemComponent,
    TheSolutionComponent,
    ProbabilityCalculatorComponent,
    TheGameComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatTabsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

What am I missing? Thank you!

**EDIT**

I edited the `app.component.html` like this to find out some more about the link "active" state:

```
<nav mat-tab-nav-bar>
  <a mat-tab-link
     *ngFor="let link of navLinks"
     [routerLink]="link.path"
     routerLinkActive #rla="routerLinkActive"
     [active]="rla.isActive">
    {{link.label}}
    <div style="color: red; margin-left: 10px;">
        <span *ngIf="rla.isActive"> Is active!</span>
        <span *ngIf="!rla.isActive"> Is not active...</span>
    </div>
  </a>
</nav>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

As it turns out, the first link in the menu always remains active (`rla.isActive`) - also when I'm navigating to other pages. All other links turn off their active state just fine, and only get activated when they are navigated to. How do I turn off the active state of the first link when navigating to other links?

**EDIT 2**

Adding `app-routing.module.ts` code:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { TheProblemComponent } from './the-problem/the-problem.component';
import { TheSolutionComponent } from './the-solution/the-solution.component';
import { TheGameComponent } from './the-game/the-game.component';
import { ProbabilityCalculatorComponent } from './probability-calculator/probability-calculator.component';

const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: TheProblemComponent },
    { path: 'the-solution', component: TheSolutionComponent },
    { path: 'the-game', component: TheGameComponent },
    { path: 'probability-calculator', component: ProbabilityCalculatorComponent }
];


@NgModule({
  imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes) ],
  exports: [ RouterModule ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Comment: The empty route path will always resolve for all paths, therefore `routerLinkActive` will always be true.

Comment: Yes!! That's it, thank you! How can I give a router path to root though, without having it resolve for all paths? The first "Home"-button is usually to root! I tried using `/`, but I get a console error `Error: Invalid configuration of route '/': path cannot start with a slash`.

Comment: Maybe you can try a home route and by default, your app will redirect to the home route?

Comment: I'd really prefer being able to have a root URL, since it looks nice to have a clean root URL for the home page. Is this not possible? This is an advanced framework, should be possible IMO! Thanks!

Comment: @MarcusEdensky i am facing exactly the same issue. did u find any solution to use the empty root path?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It doesn't work for you because every  has the same #rla variable

You can do it this way:

```html
<nav mat-tab-nav-bar>
  <a mat-tab-link
     *ngFor="let link of navLinks"
     [routerLink]="link.path"
     routerLinkActive #rla="routerLinkActive"
     [active]="link.isActive">
    {{link.label}}
  </a>
</nav>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

or with {exact:true}

```html
<nav mat-tab-nav-bar>
  <a mat-tab-link
     *ngFor="let link of navLinks"
     [routerLink]="link.path"
     routerLinkActive #rla="routerLinkActive"
     [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact:true}"
     [active]="rla.isActive">
    {{link.label}}
  </a>
</nav>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Comment: Your answer was super helpful for me to understand the problem because I was not using `*ngFor` to render the links. In such case, naming the local `#` variable differently for every link did do the job.

Answer (score 14):

Using different local variables(`#rla1`, `#rla2`) worked for me, as i was not using `*ngFor`:

```html
<nav mat-tab-nav-bar>
    <a mat-tab-link
       [routerLink]="['/home/homepage/dashboard/']"
       routerLinkActive #rla1="routerLinkActive"
       [active]="rla1.isActive">Dashboard
    </a>
    <a mat-tab-link
       [routerLink]="['/home/homepage/reports/']"
       routerLinkActive #rla2="routerLinkActive"
       [active]="rla2.isActive">Reports
    </a>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 9):

You're missing a `/` before the link:

```html
<nav mat-tab-nav-bar>
  <a mat-tab-link
     *ngFor="let link of navLinks"
     [routerLink]="['/'+link.path]"
     routerLinkActive #rla="routerLinkActive"
     [active]="rla.isActive">
    {{link.label}}
  </a>
</nav>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

EDIT: The right way here is to set a non-empty path for all routes. You can then use a wildcard with a redirect.

```ts
const APP_ROUTES: Route[] = [
  { path: 'path-1', component: OneComponent },
  { path: 'path-2', component: TwoComponent },
  { path: 'path-3', component: ThreeComponent },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: 'path-1' },
]
```

Comment: Thank you for your response Edric, but unfortunately didn't do any difference. It's strange, because I'm using the documentation https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/api#MatTabLink , and I'm new to Angular 6, so I'm not really sure what I'm missing.

Comment: @MarcusEdensky Did you correctly import `RouterModule`? Can you add more code showing your app's module?

Comment: I believe I did, but please have a look! I just added the `app.module.ts` code. Thanks!

Comment: not working for me, the underlining bar won't chase the expected item consistently. Also, this breaks the animation of the bar.

Comment: @MarcusEdensky  i am facing exactly the same issue. did u find any solution to use the empty root path?

Answer (score 6):

You need to add `[routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact:true}"` to the `a` tag.
It becomes

```html
<nav mat-tab-nav-bar>
  <a mat-tab-link
     *ngFor="let link of navLinks"
     [routerLink]="link.path"
     routerLinkActive #rla="routerLinkActive"
     [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact:true}"
     [active]="rla.isActive">
    {{link.label}}
    <div style="color: red; margin-left: 10px;">
        <span *ngIf="rla.isActive"> Is active!</span>
        <span *ngIf="!rla.isActive"> Is not active...</span>
    </div>
  </a>
</nav>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Comment: I think it should still be allowed to work with the exact:false default but it does not

Answer (score 0):

You can simply follow below code.`active` is simply bootstrap class.

```
<nav mat-tab-nav-bar>
  <a mat-tab-link
  *ngFor="let link of navLinks"
  [routerLink]="['/'+link.path]"
  routerLinkActive="active">
  {{link.label}}
  </a>
</nav>
```

OR you can do like this below instead of using material design. kindly notice 
 `routerLinkActiveOptions` is used.

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li role="presentation"
        routerLinkActive="active"
        [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}">
      <a routerLink="/">The Problem</a>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation"
        routerLinkActive="active">
      <a routerLink="/the-solution">The Solution</a>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation"
        routerLinkActive="active">
      <a [routerLink]="/the-game">The Game</a>
    </li>
    ....
    ....
 </ul>
```

Comment: Bootstrap class?

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a Directive to achieve the same effect as the other answers without cluttering templates:

```js
@Directive({selector: 'a[routerLinkActive][mat-tab-link]'})
class MatTabRouterLinkActiveDirective {
    constructor(routerLinkActive: RouterLinkActive, matTabLink: MatTabLink) {
        routerLinkActive.isActiveChange.subscribe(value => matTabLink.active = value);
    }
}
```

With this directive included in your module, all you need is the `routerLinkActive` attribute and the directive will take care of the rest:

```html
<a mat-tab-link routerLink="/foo" routerLinkActive>Foo</a>
```

This gets rid of the `#rlaXXX="routerLinkActive" [active]="rlaXXX.isActive"` boilerplate which can get quite repetitive when the tabs are listed directly in the template (as opposed to being generated from `*ngFor` or similar).