# mat-tab-nav-bar tabs not showing up

Tags: typescript, angular6, angular-material-6, mat-tab

When using the mat-tab-nav-bar from Angular Material, the tabs aren't appearing on the Angular 6 SPA.

Here is the code:

forms.component.html:

```
<nav mat-tab-nav-bar>
  <a mat-tab-link
    *ngFor="let link of [navLinks]"
    [routerLink]="[link.path]"
    routerLinkActive #rla="routerLinkActive"
    [active]="rla.isActive">
    {{link}}
  </a>
</nav>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

forms-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { NamesComponent } from './names/names.component';
import { FileNameListComponent } from './file-name-list/file-name-list.component';

const navLinks: Routes = [
    {path: 'app-names', component: NamesComponent},
    {path: 'app-file-name-list', component: FileNameListComponent},
    {path: '**', redirectTo: 'app-names'}
  ];

  @NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(navLinks)],
    exports: [
      RouterModule
    ]
  })

export class FormsRoutingModule {

}
```

forms.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-forms',
  templateUrl: './forms.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./forms.component.css']
})
export class FormsComponent  {}
```

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { MainNavComponent } from './main-nav/main-nav.component';
import { LayoutModule } from '@angular/cdk/layout';
import { MatToolbarModule, 
  MatButtonModule, 
  MatSidenavModule, 
  MatIconModule, 
  MatListModule, 
  MatTabsModule 
} from '@angular/material';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { FormsComponent } from './forms/forms.component';
import { RoutingModule } from './routing.module';
import { ReportsComponent } from './reports/reports.component';
import { NamesComponent } from './names/names.component';
import { FileNameListComponent } from './file-name-list/file-name-list.component';
import { FormsRoutingModule } from './forms-routing.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    MainNavComponent,
    FormsComponent,
    ReportsComponent,
    NamesComponent,
    FileNameListComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    LayoutModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatSidenavModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatListModule,
    MatTabsModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    RoutingModule,
    FormsRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

In forms.component.html, when I specify the navLinks individually as below the tabs do show up.  However, when I click on the app-names tab and go to the component, the tabs disappear.

```
*ngFor="let link of ['app-names','app-file-name-list']
```

So there are two issues:

1. I can't use navLinks in the *ngFor.
2. When specifying the tab names individually, the tabs disappear after I click on one of them and go to the component.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What is `navLinks`? and why are you putting it in another array while iterating?

Comment: navLinks is the routes: const navLinks: Routes = [
    {path: 'app-names', component: NamesComponent},
    {path: 'app-file-name-list', component: FileNameListComponent},
    {path: '**', redirectTo: 'app-names'}
  ];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. navLinks in forms.component

To be able to access navLinks in `forms.component.html`, you need to put them in `forms.component.ts`.

I don'T see it there in your current component. Routes (in your route config) are one thing - links are another. Your template (html) can only access the html.

2. Dissapearing navigation

Your routing configuration is different from what you want. When you look at nav links -they're in your forms component. Then you click one - and *you navigate away, to another component*. If you want these other components to be *child components*, you need to adjust route config like that too:

```
const navLinks: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'app-names',
    component: NamesComponent, 
    children: [
      { path: 'app-file-name-list', component: FileNameListComponent, },
      { path: '**', redirectTo: 'app-names' },
    ],
  }
];
```

Now your components will render in that **nested** router-outlet - not in the main one of the app.

Comment: 1. Do I have to specify navLinks in forms.component.ts as well as forms-routing.module.ts?  Similar to this example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50313246/angular-6-material-mat-tab-link-be-selected-by-underlining-bar 2. I want app-names and app-file-name-list be different tab accessible from forms.component.  So do I have to have them as child components in forms.component?

Comment: 1. Yes. You could use a common file, like a JSON or a service, with tab definitions, and then use this in both router config and forms component, but both of them need _a_ list.
2. Yes - those should be child components.

Comment: 1. Nice idea. So just add the navLinks piece of code to a Service and then call the service in forms.component.ts and forms-routing.module.ts?  Is there a way we can move this conversation to a chat?

Comment: Unfortunately not today, but if you leave more questions (here or as parts of this/other questions), I can take a look tomorrow.

Comment: For point 1. I don't understand why navLinks has to be specified in forms.component.ts and forms-routing.module.ts.  I have seen examples where the routes are only specified in app.module.ts and not app.component.ts.  I can also share code, when I get home, that I've written where I have only specified the routes in app.module.ts.

Comment: Routes are one thing. Nav links are another. You may have hardcoded nav there?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185379/discussion-between-rds80-and-zlatko).

Comment: Chat is blocked at work. I thought navLinks is a constant's name for Routes.  From the code, above in forms-routing.module.ts: "const navLinks: Routes"

Comment: aha. So, you have 3 parts here. `navLinks` in routes - it expects `{ path: <'ROUTE>', component: '<COMPONENT_NAME>' }` objects. You have the router *ngFor loop - it wants an array of strings. So you might want to put this in your forms.component: `navLinks = routes.map(route => route.path)`;

Comment: Sorry does routes come from @angular/routes?  Can you provide an example from the code above?

Comment: Routes can come from whereever you want to keep them. You seem to wanna have some sort of central config for the routes, here's an example of how it can be done: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-navlinks-around?file=src%2Fapp%2Fnav%2Fnav.component.html

Comment: Had to move this into the chat as I had to share code.